# C# Excel protected sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I am using c# to do some automation with Excel. I compile the data and create a table around it so that a user can calculate the sum of a column. Everytime I protect the sheet, no matter which options I turn true or false, I can never gain access to that feature again. Is there a  way to do it?

here is the relevant function definition from Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx

a snippet of relevant code

```
warrantySheet.Cells.Locked = false;
getWarrantySheetUsedRange().Locked = true;
warrantySheet.Protect(SHEET_PASSWORD,true, true, true,true, true, true, true,false, false,false,false,false, true,true,true);
```

here is the imgur for what I am talking about  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGgx8.jpg

Comment: post the code you are using

Comment: Need more info, what do you mean you can *never gain access to that feature again*? You Protect the spreadsheet, then you the option is to UnProtect.

Comment: You can specify during the protection that you allow user to do stuff like insert row, ...
I want to be able to still use the "autosum", "average"  and other functions of the table even when the sheet is protected.

Answer (score 0):

You're locking the used range where subtotals functionality happens (Sum, Average, Count, etc.) Assuming you only have 1 table (`ListObject`) on your sheet. Try this:

```
warrantySheet.Cells.Locked = false;
getWarrantySheetUsedRange().Locked = true;
warrantySheet.ListObjects[1].TotalsRowRange.Locked = false;
warrantySheet.Protect(SHEET_PASSWORD,true, true, true,true, true, true, true,false, false,false,false,false, true,true,true);
```